# local properties file for buildr

Tags: buildr

the buildr docs suggest using profiles.yaml for managing settings. however, i would like a way to define settings which an individual dev would use to run locally and thus shouldn't be in scm. is there a preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I ended up with:

```
path = File.dirname(@application.rakefile)
loc = YAML.load(File.read(File.join(path, "profiles.local.yml")))
Buildr.settings.profiles.merge!(loc)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution looks good.  Using buildr's `_` function you can cut it down slightly:

```
Buildr.settings.profiles.merge!(
  YAML.load(File.read(_("profiles.local.yml")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your local properties to **local.rb**, add to buildfile

`require 'local'`